# Decrypt openssl certificate

Tags: ssl, encryption, openssl, certificate, pkcs#8

I generated 3 keys / certificates using this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
AUTH='/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Android/OU=Android/CN=Android/emailAddress=android@android.com'
if [ "$1" == "" ]; then
        echo "Create a test certificate key."
        echo "Usage: $0 NAME"
        echo "Will generate NAME.pk8 and NAME.x509.pem"
        echo "  $AUTH"
        exit
fi

openssl genrsa -3 -out $1.pem 2048

openssl req -new -x509 -key $1.pem -out $1.x509.pem -days 10000 \
    -subj "$AUTH"

echo "Please enter the password for this key:"
openssl pkcs8 -in $1.pem -topk8 -outform DER -out $1.pk8 -passout stdin
```

The output is:

```
releasekey.pem
releasekey.pk8
releasekey.x509.pem
```

Then I'm trying to decrypt it using this command:

```
openssl pkcs8 -in ~/.android-certs/releasekey.pk8 -inform DER
```

So, the output is

```
alex-garmas-osx:android alex-garmash$ openssl pkcs8 -in ~/.android-

certs/releasekey.pk8 -inform DER
Enter Password:
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
CONTENT OF PRIVATE KEY HERE
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

And it works OK. `releasekey.pk8` doesn't have a passphrase

When I do the same with the command:

```
openssl pkcs8 -in ~/.android-certs/releasekey.pk8 -inform DER -nocrypt
```

I have an error:

```
140735885419528:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1200:
140735885419528:error:0D06C03A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_D2I_EX_PRIMITIVE:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:768:
140735885419528:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:700:Field=version, Type=PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO
```

In the [documentation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:Pkcs8(1)) I see that I can use option `-nocrypt`, but why is it failing?

## UPDATE

Many thanks to **@bartonjs** for the explanation. To solve this problem you need to add **-nocrypt** flag to the last command of the script, then you can use the command above to decrypt generated key

```
#!/bin/sh
AUTH='/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Android/OU=Android/CN=Android/emailAddress=android@android.com'
if [ "$1" == "" ]; then
        echo "Create a test certificate key."
        echo "Usage: $0 NAME"
        echo "Will generate NAME.pk8 and NAME.x509.pem"
        echo "  $AUTH"
        exit
fi

openssl genrsa -3 -out $1.pem 2048

openssl req -new -x509 -key $1.pem -out $1.x509.pem -days 10000 \
    -subj "$AUTH"

echo "Please enter the password for this key:"
openssl pkcs8 -in $1.pem -topk8 -outform DER -out $1.pk8 -passout stdin -nocrypt
```

Comment: From documentation `-nocrypt` _With this option an unencrypted PrivateKeyInfo structure is expected or output._ but `releasekey.pk8` is encrypted with a password. isn't it?

Comment: @pedrofb without. I wrote above: "releasekey.pk8 doesn't have a passphrase" passphrase = password. It's empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting prompted for the empty password, and it succeeds, and with `-nocrypt` it is failing.

There's a difference between "encrypted with the empty password" and "not encrypted" (though to a brute forcer, not much of one).

An unencrypted PKCS#8 blob looks like (ASN.1):

```
PrivateKeyInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
    version                   Version,
    privateKeyAlgorithm       PrivateKeyAlgorithmIdentifier,
    privateKey                PrivateKey,
    attributes           [0]  IMPLICIT Attributes OPTIONAL }
```

If it has been encrypted, then it's

```
EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
    encryptionAlgorithm  EncryptionAlgorithmIdentifier,
    encryptedData        EncryptedData }

EncryptionAlgorithmIdentifier ::= AlgorithmIdentifier

EncryptedData ::= OCTET STRING
```

So `-nocrypt` tells OpenSSL that it should expect the first structure directly, whereas yours looks like the second (notably, the first child of the SEQUENCE wasn't an INTEGER, but was another SEQUENCE).

And saying that your data was encrypted with the empty password doesn't mean it was encrypted with some sort of empty key.  The creator of the PKCS#8 file almost certainly went through the trouble of picking a random salt to the PBKDF2 algorithm, which then gets combined with the empty password to produce an output.  That data is still noise, just... easier to brute force noise than normal.